# CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE error on UPDATE of List<SObject>

Tags: apex, trigger

**Objective**

I am attempting to rollup/update some custom activity fields on the `Lead/Contact` object *after* a `Task/Event` is *inserted/updated/deleted*.

**Scenario**

Currently on the `EventTriggerHandler.cls` (using [Kevin O'Hara's Trigger framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)), I'm simply passing the `Event.WhoId`(s) to an `ActivityUtils.cls

```
private void setLeadsAndContactsLastEvent(){
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        Set<String> whoId_set = new Set<String>();
        for(Event e : (List<Event>) Trigger.old){
            if(e.whoId != null){
                whoId_set.add(e.WhoId);
            }
        }
        if(!whoId_set.isEmpty())
            ActivityUtils.setLastEventByWhoId(whoId_set);
    }
}
```

From that utility function I manipulate the data to get my finished product of `allEvents` which is an SObject list of both Leads & Contacts and then I run an UPDATE. As far as I know this is not an issue, and to be safe I even attempted just `List<Lead>` & `List<Contact>` Here's what this looks like right now:

```
List<SObject> allEvents = new List<SObject>();
allEvents.addAll( (List<SObject>)contact_map.values() );
allEvents.addAll( (List<SObject>)lead_map.values() );
UPDATE allEvents;
```

**Results**

When I debug `allEvents` I get what I would expect:

```
Contact:{Last_Touch_Event_ID__c=00UJ00000098PgZMAU,...}
Contact:{Last_Touch_Event_ID__c=00UJ00000098O8kMAE,...}
Contact:{Last_Touch_Event_ID__c=00UJ0000009HdnFMAS,...}
Lead:{Last_Touch_Event_ID__c=00UJ0000009HjQsMAK,...}
```

Again, I've tested passing and declaring Contact/Lead alone as well, same issue. The issue is someone in the rest of this debug log:

```
10:26:04.734 (1734509303)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qJ00000009DIR|Contact on Contact trigger event BeforeUpdate for [003J0000014cKHs, 003J0000016ARDS, 003J0000016cCnN]
10:26:04.756 (1756427285)|METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|01pJ0000000CYBz|ContactTriggerHandler.ContactTriggerHandler()
10:26:04.756 (1756455582)|METHOD_EXIT|[9]|ContactTriggerHandler
10:26:04.759 (1759845776)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[10]|01pJ0000000CYBz|<init>()
10:26:04.760 (1760564821)|METHOD_ENTRY|[10]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.TriggerHandler()
10:26:04.760 (1760660045)|METHOD_EXIT|[10]|TriggerHandler
10:26:04.760 (1760668995)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[11]|01pJ0000000CKH0|<init>()
10:26:04.760 (1760765404)|METHOD_ENTRY|[32]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.setTriggerContext()
10:26:04.760 (1760808023)|METHOD_ENTRY|[104]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.setTriggerContext(String, Boolean)
10:26:04.760 (1760932058)|METHOD_EXIT|[104]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.setTriggerContext(String, Boolean)
10:26:04.760 (1760938679)|METHOD_EXIT|[32]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.setTriggerContext()
10:26:04.760 (1760943275)|CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[11]|01pJ0000000CKH0|<init>()
10:26:04.760 (1760947658)|CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[10]|01pJ0000000CYBz|<init>()
10:26:04.760 (1760956817)|METHOD_ENTRY|[10]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.run()
10:26:04.760 (1760967800)|METHOD_ENTRY|[42]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.validateRun()
10:26:04.760 (1760993339)|METHOD_ENTRY|[159]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.getHandlerName()
10:26:04.761 (1761249795)|METHOD_EXIT|[159]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.getHandlerName()
10:26:04.761 (1761280453)|METHOD_EXIT|[42]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.validateRun()
10:26:04.761 (1761291192)|METHOD_ENTRY|[44]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.addToLoopCount()
10:26:04.761 (1761314601)|METHOD_ENTRY|[143]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.getHandlerName()
10:26:04.761 (1761449362)|METHOD_EXIT|[143]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.getHandlerName()
10:26:04.761 (1761502434)|METHOD_EXIT|[44]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.addToLoopCount()
10:26:04.761 (1761634247)|METHOD_ENTRY|[50]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.beforeUpdate()
10:26:04.761 (1761656256)|METHOD_EXIT|[50]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.beforeUpdate()
10:26:04.761 (1761661195)|METHOD_EXIT|[10]|01pJ0000000CKH0|TriggerHandler.run()
10:26:05.043 (1761675177)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
10:26:05.043|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 6 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 76 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 4 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 93 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

My research so far says that something is causing the Trigger to re-fire some how causing the `CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE` error but I've checked and even removed any trigger events on the Lead/Contact trigger handler  (since they are being UPDATED).

Any feedback to help debug this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE is not an error, it's just a part of the debug log that indicates how close you are to various limits. Is there more to the debug log than what you pasted? If not, then there is no error.

What happens when you update an event that should fire this code? Do the roll-ups update? Do you get an error message in the browser?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm seeing hundreds more lines that apparently are fired because of other triggers from a previous developer, as well as some managed packages so I'm decoding now. Previously I posted because no the rollup was not working, but just now in the midst of my clean up process I tested again and SUCCESS! I'm going to do some more housecleaning and will update if there is any new details but otherwise this may be a non-issue as you suggested. Thanks for confirming though, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE is not an error**, it's just a part of the debug
>   log that indicates how close you are to various limits.  –  *Matt Britton Mar 10 at 18:42*