# Apex class exiting without writing record

Tags: apex

I'm writing a scheduled Apex class to retrieve data from an external web service, I can see it make both it's callouts in the debug log and do the JSON processing it's supposed to do but it never writes the record it's supposed to write and exits 'CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE'  Here's my code:

```
global class  Salestreegetcontacts3 implements schedulable{
 public User STUser{get;set;}
 public string cstUsername {get;set;}
 public string cstPassword {get;set;}
 public url st_Today{get;set;}
 public url st_Vault{get;set;}
 public string kind {get;set;}
 public string title {get;set;}
 public string description{get;set;}
 public date startdate{get;set;}
 public datetime startdatetime{get;set;}
 public url self{get;set;}
 public Contact__c contact;
 public map<string, string> UserMap;   
 public map<string, string> contactmap;

     global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        returncontact();
     }
     @future(callout=true)
     static void returncontact(){
        string xAuthToken;
        string cstNode;
        string ClientAcctId;
        Id STUserId;

    If (xAuthToken == null){

    User STUser = [select Id, X_Auth_token__c, CSTlastupdate__c, CST_Node__c, Client_Account_Id__c from User where User.X_Auth_token__c != null ];
    Id UserID = STUser.Id;
    string Cliacc = STUser.Client_Account_Id__c;


    if(StUser.X_Auth_Token__c == null){
    system.debug('X Auth not returned at UserDataMap');
    }
    else
    {
    system.debug('X Auth returned at UserDataMap');
    }
    if(STUser.X_Auth_Token__c != null){
map<string, string> Usermap = new map<string, string> ();
Usermap.put('Id', string.valueof(STUser.Id));
Usermap.put('xAuth', STUser.X_Auth_token__c);
Usermap.put('LastUpdate', string.valueof(STUser.CSTlastupdate__c));
Usermap.put('Node', STUser.CST_Node__c);
Usermap.put('Client_Account', STUser.Client_Account_Id__c);


    if(xAuthToken == null){


    xAuthToken = STUser.X_Auth_token__c;
    cstNode = STUser.CST_Node__c;
    ClientAcctId = STUser.Client_Account_Id__c;
    STUserId = STUser.Id;

        map<string, string> eventmap = new map<string, string>();

    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res1 = new HttpResponse();
    Http http1 = new Http();
    string endpointUrl = '';
    Date Todaysdate = Date.today();
    String sMonth = String.valueof(Todaysdate.month());
    String sDay = String.valueof(Todaysdate.day());
    if(sMonth.length()==1){
        sMonth = '0' + sMonth;
        }
    if(sDay.length()==1){
      sDay = '0' + sDay;
      }
      String sToday = String.valueof(Todaysdate.year()) + '-'  + sMonth + '-' + sDay ;

    endpointUrl += 'https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/node/' + cstNode;
    endpointUrl += '/calendar?from=' + sToday;
    endpointUrl += '&to=' + sToday;
    req1.setMethod('GET' ); // Method Type
    req1.setEndpoint(endpointUrl);
     req1.setheader('Accept', '*/*');
    req1.setheader('Authorization' , xAuthToken);

        res1 = http1.send(req1);
        if(res1.getBody() != null){



  JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res1.getBody());


  while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
                (parser.getText() == 'st:vault')) {
                parser.nextToken();
                parser.nextToken();
                parser.nextToken();
                //st_Vault = parser.getText();

                eventmap.put('St_vault', parser.getText());

        string self1;
        string  st_Emails;
        string st_Phones;
        string st_Opps;
        string st_notes;
        string vault_key;
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
        string address1;
        string address2;
        string city;
        string prov_state;
        string country;
        string postal_cd;
        string email;
        string phone1;
        string phone2;
        string lead_id;
        string lead_source;

        map<string, string> contactmap = new map<string,string>();

    //if (Usermap.containsKey('xAuth') != null && eventmap.containskey('St_vault') != null){
    HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res2 = new HttpResponse();
    Http http2= new Http();

    req2.setMethod('GET' ); // Method Type
    req2.setEndpoint(eventmap.get('St_vault'));
    req2.setheader('Accept', '*/*');
    req2.setheader('Authorization' , xAuthToken);

        res2 = http2.send(req2);
        if(res2.getBody() != null){
           // public static void parseJSONString() {


JSONParser parser1 = JSON.createParser(res2.getBody());

while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
    if (parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {

    while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'st:emails')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();
            parser1.nextToken();
            //st_Emails = parser.getText();
            parser1.nextToken();
            st_Emails = parser.getText();
            //contactmap.put('st_Emails', parser1.getText());

    while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'st:phones')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();
            parser1.nextToken();
            //st_Phones = parser.getText();
            parser1.nextToken();
            st_Phones = parser.getText();
            //contactmap.put('st_Phone', parser1.getText());


 while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'st:opps')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();
            parser1.nextToken();
            //st_Opps = parser.getText();
            parser1.nextToken();
            st_Opps = parser.getText();
            //contactmap.put('st_Opps', parser1.getText());

while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'st:notes')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();
            parser1.nextToken();
            st_Notes = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('st_Notes', parser1.getText());

        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'vault_key')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            vault_key = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('vault_key', parser1.getText());

        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'first_name')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            first_name = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('first_name', parser1.getText());

        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'last_name')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            last_name = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('last_name', parser1.getText());

        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'address_line1')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            address1 = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('address1', parser1.getText());

        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'address_line2')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            address2 = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('address2', parser1.getText());


        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'city')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            city = parser.getText();

           // contactmap.put('city', parser1.getText());

        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'prov_state')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            prov_state = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('prov_state', parser1.getText());

        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'country')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            country = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('country', parser1.getText());


        while (parser1.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser1.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
        (parser1.getText() == 'postal_cd')) { 
            parser1.nextToken();

            postal_cd = parser.getText();

            //contactmap.put('postal_cd', parser1.getText());



            Contact__c contactup = new Contact__c();
            contactup.Vault_Key__c = vault_key;
            contactup.First_Name__c = first_name;
            contactup.Last_Name__c = last_name;
            contactup.Street_1__c = address1;
            contactup.Street_2__c = address2;
            contactup.City__c = city;
            contactup.State_Province__c = prov_state;
            contactup.Country__c = country;
            contactup.Zip_Code__c = postal_cd;
            contactup.Client_Account__c = Cliacc;
            contactup.OwnerID = UserId;
            upsert contactup;


 }

 }

}
}
}
}
}
}
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Can anyone tell me how I get it to write my record?  Thanks.

Comment: Restrict your logging and use System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Message'); to see your debugs.  It just means your logs got too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has [already been resolved on this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68821/cumulative-limit-usage-error-on-update-of-listsobject) and should be closed.

> CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE is not an error, it's just a part of the debug log that indicates how close you are to various limits.